# How do I allow CORS between two elastic beanstalk servers?

Tags: php, node.js, https, cors, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am having trouble sending a POST request between two AWS elastic beanstalk servers. I configured the CORS in the receiving server.

```
app.use(cors({
    origin: "https://www.petsource.app/"}));
```

And it shows up in the browser when I run the request.

[Error response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0lOZ.png)

But the request still shows up as an error and blocks the request. I have gotten this to work on localhost so I am wondering if it is elastic beanstalk?

Comment: Can you provide a text-form of that cors error in your question? Also... what tool is reporting the error

Comment: CORS makes sense for browsers and not for communication between servers.

Comment: The error says "Ensure CORS requesting origin matches resource's allowed origin". The error appears in the google browser console when I open the link to the webpage. And when I look at the database no data has been transmitted.